# Remove Directory recursively

Tags: php, recursion

I wrote a custom remove function in PHP. The function call is used recursively, but when calling the function, I get an error output:

```
// custom delete directory function
function deleteDirectory($dir) {
    if (!file_exists($dir)) return true;
    if (!is_dir($dir) || is_link($dir)) return unlink($dir);
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
        if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') continue;

        // THIS IS LINE 32 LIKE MENTIONED IN THE ERROR
        if (!$this->deleteDirectory($dir . "/" . $item)) {

             // THIS IS LINE 33 LIKE MENTIONED IN THE ERROR
            chmod($dir . "/" . $item, 0777);
            if (!$this->deleteDirectory($dir . "/" . $item)) return false;
        };
    }

    // THIS IS LINE 37 LIKE MENTIONED IN THE ERROR
    return rmdir($dir);
}

function cleanup() {
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->workFolder), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
    foreach ($files as $name => $fileObject) {
        if (is_file($name)) {
            unlink($name);
        } else if (is_dir($name)) {
            system("/bin/chmod -R 0777 $name");
            $this->deleteDirectory($name);
        }
    }
    $this->deleteDirectory($this->workFolder);
}
```

I tried the approach with "$this->deleteDirectory()"
but now I receive a totally different error:

```
Warning: rmdir(/tmp/533aab0362830/.) [function.rmdir]: Invalid argument in /usr/www/users/kontug/api.medifaktor.de/webservice/passkit/class/Pass.php on line 37

Warning: rmdir(/tmp/533aab0362830/../.ICE-unix) [function.rmdir]: Operation not permitted in /usr/www/users/kontug/api.medifaktor.de/webservice/passkit/class/Pass.php on line 37

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Operation not permitted in /usr/www/users/kontug/api.medifaktor.de/webservice/passkit/class/Pass.php on line 33

Warning: rmdir(/tmp/533aab0362830/../.ICE-unix) [function.rmdir]: Operation not permitted in /usr/www/users/kontug/api.medifaktor.de/webservice/passkit/class/Pass.php on line 37
```

Comment: Where you call the function ?

Comment: And what's on line 32 of `/webservice/passkit/class/Pass.php`?

Comment: Function is part of a class: missing `$this->` or static reference.

Comment: You should debug step by step (`var_udmp($dir)`)

Comment: I tried the var_dump, but without any outcome. I thought about the "operation not permitted", but I set the chmod to 0777 before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A recursive remove directory function for PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407338/a-recursive-remove-directory-function-for-php)

Comment: I think you have an issue with PHP language. What the `$dir` print at the beginning of the method ? Throw an Exception if `$dir` is empty. Maybe you don't have the right permission on the folder so you're not able to use the `chmod()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use classes you must call the method as `$this->methodName()`.
Below is snipped which worked for me.
You can try this.  If it gives permission error then you can add **chmod** function.
Remember you can not traverse a directory if you don't have read permission.  So set the permission first.

```
   function deleteDirectory($dir) {
        if (!file_exists($dir)) return true;
        if (!is_dir($dir)) return unlink($dir);
        foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
            if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') continue;
            if (!$this->deleteDirectory($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$item)) return false;
        }
        return rmdir($dir);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this method you suggested: and inserted the following line after "foreach" and before the first if statement: chmod($dir . "/" . $item, 0777); But this is not accepted by the script

Comment: I mean if you are trying to access a directory outside the /var/www (i.e root of execution) folder. Then from terminal set the permission. Not from the code. In code don't set permission in recursive function.

Comment: ah okay. I am creating dynamically temp folders with the sys_get_temp_dir() function. How can I set the permission to them?

Comment: Rather than I'll say use something like this before calling the deleteDirectory method. system("/bin/chmod -R $mod $dir");

Comment: This seems to work, but I still get an error for the line:
return rmdir($dir); (Invalid Argument, and operation not permitted);

Warning: rmdir(/tmp/533ab2ea4a033/.) [function.rmdir]: Invalid argument in /usr/www/users/kontug/api.medifaktor.de/webservice/passkit/class/Pass.php on line 35

Warning: rmdir(/tmp/533ab2ea4a033/../.ICE-unix) [function.rmdir]: Operation not permitted in /usr/www/users/kontug/api.medifaktor.de/webservice/passkit/class/Pass.php on line 35

Comment: Operation not permitted means you are running the command as www-data user. You have to be root or any other user if you want access to other directories you can try this "sudo /bin/chomod..." if you are on ubuntu this will run it as root.

Comment: This error is just because user www-data don't have permission to delete those files and directories. Use that system function with sudo set permission and then call delete method.

Comment: just one more question! :) The "sudo /bin/chmod" can be called within PHP?

Comment: yes it can be called in php it will make a System call but I'll say first try without sudo. More info about exec, system is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru

Comment: I just tried the call without sudo, but still no difference..Sorry. I don't want to bug you! I just edited the question: The cleanup() method. Is this correct?

Comment: Use sudo then because current user doesn't have enough permission to modify it.

Comment: I did this as well: 

system("sudo /bin/chmod -R 0777 $files");

But still no change.. I am really sorry I am not up to speed here :)

Comment: Do I call the system function at the right place at all?

Comment: not $files it should be parent of directory eg. /temp. So it will recursively set the permission.

Comment: put the system function immediately after opening cleanup function.

Comment: it will look like this function cleanup(){ system("/bin/chmod -R 0777 $this->workFolder"); ...

Comment: So I tried this: function cleanup() {system("/bin/chmod -R 0777 $this->workFolder"); (...)}  But still the same message.

Comment: ohh.. then try this system("/usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod -R 0777 $this->workingFolder");

Comment: You won't believe it Vivek... still no change.... I still get the Operation not permitted

Comment: hmm... from terminal are you able to set the permission? change the $this->working folder to a constant like /temp then try

Comment: I believe after setting the permission from terminal your issue will be solved. Hope so. Best Luck.

Comment: I don't seem to have access by terminal to the server... I think I don't have root access

Answer (score 2):

If the function belongs to a class then it should be called like this

```
$this->deleteDirectory($dir . "/" . $item)
```

instead of

```
deleteDirectory($dir . "/" . $item)
```

Comment: If it were part of a class, wouldn't it be a "method"?

Comment: Yes you are right @ghoti

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841605/what-is-a-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function

Comment: yes, we would call it a method, but php does not say 'method' in error's, or in class definition. So the term 'function' is a bit amibuous here. So in fact @Dikesh is (most probably) right in his suggestion.