# I can't understand the meaning of method in PHP

Tags: php, methods, call

I am a beginner of php and learning PHP on Codecademy.com but I am not able to understand the meaning of METHOD and how to call a method. Can anyone explain me please.

Comment: Start here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: I just googled [what is the difference between method and function in php](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+the+difference+between+method+and+function+in+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for you. And it returned a featured question in Stack Overflow as first result! So I'm going with **duplicated question**, sorry.

Comment: Can't explain in 2-3 lines or 2-3 para. You have to read the manual given above or to refer any book.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a difference between a method and a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841605/what-is-a-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)

Comment: No it is not any duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

Method is actually a function used in the context of a class/object.

When you create a function outside of a class/object, you can call it a function but when you create a function inside a class, you can call it a method.

```
class foo{
   public function bar(){ // a method
     ........
   }
}

function bar(){  // a function not part of an object
}
```

So an object can have methods (functions) and properties (variables).

Comment: $foo = new foo;  $foo->bar();  how to call a method.