# How to make a function called by label in php?

Tags: php

You all php developers surely know about `include 'Some_File.ext'`, I want to create a function which uses the same `call method` as `include`, `echo` and `require`. They all have in common that they are called with an "argument" (I mean the defined function), how would I possible do the same to one of mine?

```
// | I want to call a function like "cps 'SomeWhatValue';"
// | The function will contain of
    function cps($value){
       //do something with $value
       return $result_or_state;
    }
//  Call method:   cps        $value;
//               Argument1 : $Arugment2
```

But how would I possibly define the function with this label?

Comment: You should call function like `pst('Some Value')`

Comment: 1. In php they are called functions. 2. You can check everything in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: [Introduction to OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: @Mohammad I am sure of that, but my question is about how to make a method stub of a function

Comment: @Dekel don't forget [they're called methods when in a class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4841628/4233593).

Comment: @JeffPuckettII, correct, however I really don't think this is the case here :)

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're asking.  Your example is already a method stub, you declared the function but haven't yet implemented the functionality.  Maybe you should add which language you are coming from since stubs have different meanings in different languages.

Comment: @Machavity, I don't see how the marked duplicate relates to the question, especially with the clarification of method stubs.

Comment: I think you're asking how to call a method with a value. Understanding that a method is a part of a full class, instatiate your object, then call your method like $object->pst('some value');

Comment: @Machavity, I cleared it up. Please reopen

Comment: I'm still not sure where you're going with it but it's opened as promised. Good luck to you

Comment: @Machavity  Thank you very much