# How can I tell what functions are available in a node.js module

Tags: node.js

When I download a third party module for example:

```
npm install twitter
```

How can I tell what functions/methods are available when I create an object. Example:

```
var twitter = require('twitter');
```

This also applies with the "hello world webserver" you commonly see with node.js

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello Http');
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Is there some command I can run on the http module to get a list of functions/methods like .createServer()

I could dig around for online documentation about the specific module but was hoping there was a command line way of simply retrieving a list of available functions/methods

Btw... in node.js what do they call them? Functions or Methods?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777/method-vs-message-vs-function-vs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try?

```
var http = require('http');
console.log(http)
```

To see what is in object there is also beautiful module called "util":

```
var util = require('util'); 
console.log(util.inspect(http))
```

util.inspect returns string representation of object.

Answer (score 1):

At the `node` prompt, just type:

```
require('twitter')
```

That will dump the function and data members of the module to the console.

The function and method terms are largely interchangeable in node.js.